# Is it possible to create an operator+ function for C++'s string class? And to concatenate "literals"?

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

Can I arbitrarily write an `operator+()` function for C++'s `string` class so I don't have to use `<sstream>` to concatenate strings?

For example, instead of doing

```
someVariable << "concatenate" << " this";
```

Can I add an `operator+()` so I can do

```
someVariable = "concatenate" + " this";
```

?

Comment: `+` operator by default concatenates std::string. What new are you trying to do? [operator + documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/operator+/)

Comment: Aaah. I missed that. That didn't show up in any of the top results for "c++ concatenate string". So does that work with literals?

Comment: No. For the `+` operator to work at least one operand must be of type `std::string`. In your case both are of type `const char*` as @AusCBloke said.

Comment: Hmmmm... Can I create an operator+() function to add literals together? (I'm guessing that I can!)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `std::string` `operator+` *does* concatenate two `std::string`s. Your problem however is that `"concatenate"` and `"this"` aren't two `std::string`s; they're of type `const char []`.

If you want to concatenate the two literals `"concatenate"` and `"this"` for whatever reason (usually so you can split strings over multiple lines) you do:

```
string someVariable = "concatenate" " this";
```

And the compiler will realise that you actually want `string someVariable = "concatenate this";`

If `"concatenate"` and `"this"` were stored in `std::string`s then the following **is** valid:

```
string s1 = "concatenate";
string s2 = " this";

string someVariable = s1 + s2;
```

**OR**

```
string s1 = "concatenate";

string someVariable = s1 + " this";
```

Or even

```
string someVariable = string("concatenate") + " this";
```

Where `" this"` will be automatically *converted* into an `std::string` object when `operator+` is invoked. For this conversion to take place at least one of the operands **must** be of type `std::string`.

Comment: @NicolBolas thanks for the edit, I was thinking of adding that one in.

Comment: Oh, ok, I think I get it: the operator+ only works when there is at LEAST one `std::string` being "added" with a literal. Does it work if I do `string someVariable = s1 + " this" + " that";`? (I also updated my question.)

Comment: @trusktr yes it does, because the statement is equated from left to right, ie. `(s1 + " this") + " that";`. So `" this"` will be concatenated to the result of `(s1 + " this")`, which is of type `std::string`.

Comment: So if I do `string someVariable = " this" + " that" + s1;` then it won't work?

Comment: @trusktr that's exactly right, this is the error you will receive: `error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [6]’ and ‘const char [6]’ to binary ‘operator+’`

Comment: THanks! Hmmmm... I'm guessing its possible to create an overloaded operator+ for const char [] types, right?

Comment: @trusktr, sorry - you can't override `operator+` for built-in types, which includes pointers and char arrays. The type is determined by the left-hand operand.

Comment: @trusktr Mark bet me to it. You can't do that, but even if you could for C style strings it'd introduce all sorts of potential memory leak problems, which is why a class, such as `std::string`, is a much better option and will look after memory allocating and freeing upon creation and destruction.